# ASP MVC2 Calling different views

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

Hello fellow programmers!

I am currently stuck in a school assignment.  I am working with ASP.NET, MVC2 (I know, it's old :( )  Here is the situation:  I have a controller who will decide with an if statement what view to return.  For example:

Here is a method within my controller:

```
public ActionResult Verification()
{
    String lastName = Request["lastName"];
    String name = Request["name"];
    String dob = Request["dob"];
    String phone = Request["phone"];
    String selection = Request["selection"];

    Verification verifying = new Verification(lastName, name, dob, phone, selection);

    String other = verifying.returnIfGood();

    if (!(other == ""))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("probleme1");
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("probleme2");
    }
}
```

RedirectToAction seem to point directly at a view, but I also need to pass the view a string to work with.  I also noticed if I call a method within my controller, no view gets returned, which I am a little confused about.  I am trying to stay away from ajax and jquery since I haven't seen those yet.  Is there any way to do this using only c#?

Comment: You want to return view form another controller ?

Comment: No, same controller, different action.

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to ajax call with query string like

```
Controller/action?viewname='abc'
```

Then
Get on **actionresult method**

Then **redirect to action** on the basis of viewName.

Or

```
Redirect(controller/actionName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite confusing as to what you're trying to accomplish, and some of the comments seem to indicate a misunderstanding of what is actually going on. Given that, I'm going to try to address your question but may be missing the mark.

`RedirectToAction` does not "point directly at a view". It causes an HTTP 302 response to be sent to the browser with a new URL which the browser then turns around and requests with a new GET operation.

Given that you haven't provided the code for the `probleme1` and `probleme2` action methods I have no idea what other logic might live there. If all they do is return a view you could rewrite your `Verification` method to return the view instead and include the "string to work with" as a model.

```
public ActionResult Verification()
{
    // code omitted for brevity...

    if (!(other == ""))
    {
        return View("probleme1", "some string");
    }
    else
    {
        return View("probleme2", "some other string");
    }
}
```

If the logic in `probleme1` and `probleme2` is more complex and you really need to preserve the `RedirectToAction` approach you could set a value in `TempData` in your `Verification` method and then pass that value along in the other methods.

```
public ActionResult Verification()
{
    // code omitted for brevity...

    if (!(other == ""))
    {
        TempData.ModelString = "some string";
        return RedirectToAction("probleme1");
    }
    else
    {
        TempData.ModelString = "some other string";
        return RedirectToAction("probleme2");
    }
}

public ActionResult probleme1()
{
    return View(<view name>, TempData.ModelString);
}
```

In this case you need to use `TempData` and not `ViewData` as the former will survive the redirect while the latter will not. Put another way, `TempData` is for holding information between controller actions during a redirect, `ViewData` is for sending information from the controller to the view.